# Print Bill from POS Printer on Web Base PHP laravel application

Tags: laravel, web, printing, epson, pos

I have developed web based POS system. Then I hosted that in cpanel server. I can print the bill in localhost but not in live server. I used ESC/POS Print Driver for that. Can you help me solve this Problem?

```
<?php
 public function test() {
    try {
        $connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("POS Printer");
        $printer = new Printer($connector);
        $printer->text("Hello World!");
        $printer->cut();
         $printer->close();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Couldn't print to this printer: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: Can you show us sample codes on how are you printing the bill? Is there any error produced in the browser?

Comment: i have add the code

Comment: What package are you using? this: https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php

What output are you receiving in the browser? Is there any error?

Comment: Failed to print. Command "smbclient '//sg2plcpnl0072.prod.sin2.secureserver.net/POS Printer' -c 'print -' -N -m SMB2" failed with exit code 127: sh: smbclient: command not found

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to print at the user's printer? Or the server's printer?

Comment: Based on your code. You have to install `smbclient` in your cpanel server and the cpanel server must have a direct connection to a printer.

Comment: cpane server is godaddy hosting account can i do this?

Comment: Ok let's go back to my other question, do you want to print it on the user's printer? (The one who is using the browser). Or you want to print it on the server's printer?

Comment: yes i want to print on user printer it’s usb epson printer. who using the browser.

Comment: Ok, the package you're currently using will print it to the server's printer, you may want to render the the content to a pdf and print that pdf. I suggest you use this package: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Comment: That mean remote server cant access to the printer via browser?

Comment: Yes, the remote server doesn't have access to the user's printer. If you render it via HTML or PDF, you can print that document.

Comment: thank you for your help. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question is, what are you trying to achive?

1. Are you trying to print to the server's printer? - I noticed in your code, the package you're using, your server must have a direct connection to a printer. Which currently doesn't have a connection to any printer.
2. Are you trying to print to the user's printer? - If you just want to print to the user's printer, just render a normal HTML (or render it to a PDF since you want to print a bill) then print that document on your browser.